# Protect cells with data upon saving, remaining cells should be editable when opened

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am working on an excel sheet to track down the issuance of devices. I want all the members of my team to be able to edit the sheet, but once they fill the fields and save, those fields where data is entered should be locked. later on no one should be able to edit the rows with data in it, but should be able to edit the empty rows and save. is it possible for someone to Guide me on this?

[image: sheet]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

Use an [Excel structured table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c#:%7E:text=To%20quickly%20create%20a%20table,row%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.) to hold the data add the empty rows that users are going to fill

**Step 1**

Name the table `TableIssuances` (or something that matches the code below)

[image: ExcelTable]

---

**Step 2**

Add this code to the ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Module1.LockTableFilledCells
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Module1.LockTableFilledCells
End Sub
```

Where to put the code:
[image: WhereToPutWorkbookCode]

---

**Step 3**

And add this to a standard module (read the code's comments and adjust it to suit your needs):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
Public Sub LockTableFilledCells()

    ' Define the sheet holding the table
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    
    
    ' Unprotect the sheet
    Dim sheetPassword As String
    sheetPassword = ""
    targetSheet.Unprotect Password:=sheetPassword
    
    ' Define the table holding the data
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range("TableIssuance").ListObject
    
    ' Loop through rows and check if No. is filled
    Dim tableCell As Range
    For Each tableCell In targetTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells
        
        ' Lock the row cells if No. column has a value
        targetTable.ListRows(tableCell.Row - targetTable.HeaderRowRange.Row).Range.Locked = (tableCell.Value <> vbNullString)
    
    Next tableCell

    targetSheet.Protect Password:=sheetPassword

End Sub
```

Where to put the code:
[image: WhereToPutModuleCode]

NOTE: If you need to add more rows to the table (as they won't be added automatically because sheet would be locked), just unlock the sheet and add them before saving.

Give it a try and let me know if it works

Comment: Thank You. will try this and will let you know. seems this will work perfect for me.